# DNS Leak Detection

Tags: dns, sniffer

While checking my personal VPN server for DNS leaks (and finding them), it got me thinking. If I'm a network owner who hosts a website, and I sniff and log all in/outbound on my web servers, is there any way I can identify HTTP requests being made from users with DNS leaks?

Comment: Your scenario is unclear: where is the relationship between the webserver, your network, and the users? Where are the users? Where is the DNS traffic being generated?